# Running curl "http://bas.company.com:9200/dispatcher/_search?q=_id:832238" manually passes but fails through script

Tags: python

Running curl "http://bas.company.com:9200/dispatcher/_search?q=_id:832238" manually passes but through the script it fails as follows ,error below ,can anyone suggest what is wrong here and how to overcome it?

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call,Popen,PIPE

gerrit = '832238'

escmd= ("curl \"http://bas.company.com:9200/dispatcher/_search?q=_id:%s\"" %(gerrit)).split(' ')
espipe = Popen(escmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(output, error)=  espipe.communicate()

#print output
if espipe.returncode != 0:
    print "OUTPUT"
    print output
    raise IOError, "elastic search command %s failed" % (escmd)
```

Error:-

```
IOError: phcommand ['curl', '"http://bas.company.com:9200/dispatcher/_search?q=_id:832238"'] failed
```

Comment: Why do you use `curl` when there are perfectly good Python libraries for this? In particular, check out [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes around the URL are erroneous. They are allowed (and sometimes even necessary) when the command line is parsed by the shell, but here, no shell is involved.